# Referencing a column in a table: $ operator is invalid for atomic vector

Tags: r

I am trying to run the following code

```
Newdata2 = df3%>%
   mutate(unemployedempPopRatio = Unemployed * empPopRatio)

With homoskedastic error
fit4 = lm(Satisfaction~Unemployed+empPopRatio+unemployedempPopRatio,Newdata2)%>%
stargazer(header = FALSE, type = 'latex')

With cluster error
cls_err2 = cluster.vcov(fit4, Newdata2$country)
Y = coeftest(fit4,cls_err2)
stargazer(Y, header = FALSE, type = 'latex')
```

But I am getting an error message that says '$ operator is invalid for atomic vector'. I used the $ operator in the third last line. I checked the type of Newdata2 and it is a list. I am completely new to R and am not sure what went wrong. It would be great if someone could point it out. Thank you.

Comment: use `dput()` to provide a minimal example please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a reproducible question as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  include your data (as a dataframe object or use dput("yourdata"),  This will make it more likely to get a good answer.